# Passing list of objects in Postman POST request -Body

Tags: api, http-post, postman, frombodyattribute

I have this syntax in *API-HTTP POST* request

```
public IHttpActionResult SyncWealthItemsForAccount([FromBody] List<IntegrationWealthItem> wealthItems, Data.EnumerationsIntegration.IntegrationType integrationType, string accountGuidId)
```

I want to test it in Postman:I pass Authorization and content-type in header:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

This is the way I'm passing the WealthItems list

[image]

**[0].ExternalID means WealthItems[0].ExternalID**

I guess its not the correct way of passing it. I have the error below

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "wealthItems": [
            "Ambiguous match found."
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Why does it feel like your request isn't the right format ? They "Key" parameter seems ominous. You are passing it as "x-www-form-urlencoded" - Is this how the server expects ?

Comment: @WilfredClement I dont know how to pass and set it at all. thats just my guess. form-data is not working ,returns error

Comment: What does the API specification say ? Is that an open API that you are hitting ? I can check for the details in that case. The response that you see is a valid response from the client since they expect the response to be ( for an example ) XML, JSON etc

Comment: @WilfredClement I've just created it , the syntax is specified in question . and its POST request

Comment: I don't see the API specification in the question, Is this a localhost that you are hitting at ? I'd give it a try if its open

Comment: @WilfredClement I'm still coding it. its not in production, still Local. my main question is "how can we test API with Body of type List<Object> in Postman?"

Answer (score 4):

example is if

```
@POST
    @Path("update_accounts")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PermissionRequired(Permissions.UPDATE_ACCOUNTS)
    void createLimit(List<AccountUpdateRequest> requestList) throws RuntimeException;
```

where AccountUpdateRequest :

```
public class AccountUpdateRequest {
    private Long accountId;
    private AccountType accountType;
    private BigDecimal amount;
...
}
```

then your postman request would be:
http://localhost:port/update_accounts

```
[
         {
            "accountType": "LEDGER",
            "accountId": 11111,
            "amount": 100
         },
         {
            "accountType": "LEDGER",
            "accountId": 2222,
            "amount": 300
          },
         {
            "accountType": "LEDGER",
            "accountId": 3333,
            "amount": 1000
          }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Request must be passed as JSON. So you should set Headers section in Postman to have **Content-Type** to be **application/json**.
[image]

Your body section in postman should have the option **Raw** chosen and the body can be like the snippet below, 
[image]
Note: In this sample **MessagePartTransfer** is a list and each MessagePartTransfer has 2 properties - MessagePartId and MessagePartTypeId

**Service Method that is being tested:**

```
public ICollection<MessagePartTransferResponse> DistributeMessages(ICollection<MessagePartTransfer> messageParts, long applicationId, long transactionId)
```

**MessageTransferPart class and properties:**

```
[DataContract(Name = "MessagePartTransfer")]
public class MessagePartTransfer
{
    public MessagePartTransfer();

    [DataMember]
    public long MessagePartId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long MessagePartTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

**Postman request Body: (In this example I am sending 2 objects of type MessagePartTransfer)**

```
[
    {

        "MessagePartId": 1,
        "MessagePartTypeId":2
    },
    {
        "MessagePartId":3,
        "MessagePartTypeId":4
    }
 ]
```